# Does Theory of Constraints weigh in on marginal vs conditional bottlenecks?

Tags: constraint

I have a modelling project using a [Kelly network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_network).

An observation I have made is that the bottlenecks based on the [marginal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution) of service times is not always the same as the bottlenecks based the [conditional distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability_distribution) of service times where the conditioning event is the customer class.

It is an analogous problem to [Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox) except we're considering the set of bottlenecks instead of the reversing of trends.

There may exist a [Pareto front](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_front) of allocation options that involve either exploiting the marginal vs conditional constraints of a system.

Does [TOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_constraints) weigh in on how I should consider marginal bottlenecks vs conditional bottlenecks?